# Can't open Swift realm databases with Browser, need to update even using the latest RealmSwift version

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, realm

I'm doing this [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/112544/realm-tutorial-getting-started) and there they use `pod 'RealmSwift', '~> 0.98'`. But when I try to open the `default.realm`file with the Realm Browser `Version 2.0.0 (78)`. There is always the alert

`'default.realm' is at an older file format version and must be upgraded before it can be opened. Would you like to proceed?`

[image]

So I tried to use the [latest version of RealmSwift](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#installation). Even with using the latest version, the message appears.

When I proceed and upgrade the file, I can open it and see also the records. But the problem is, when I close the realm browser after this and start the app again, an error appears

`fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: ... "Unable to open a realm at path ... Unsupported Realm file format version."`

**Note**: As in the tutorial mentioned, they use try! instead of try and do/catch for simplifying

So how can I open the realm file with or without upgrading it and still have an working app after accessing the file again with app?

Searched for other solutions on SO, but didn't find one so far.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your goal is: do you want to be using the newest Realm version, and are having trouble migrating your existing local realm files? Also, when you say you used the latest version of RealmSwift, you updated your Cocoapod to the newest version? The screenshot you're showing indicates a local upgrade of 1 file, not a persistent solution for your app.

Comment: The goal is just to open the realm file after adding some records via the app. Then to see the added records in the realm browser. After closing the realm browser to continue working with the app. But as I mentioned in my question, I can only open the file with the browser after proceeding with upgrade, but then the error occurs with `Unable to open realm at...`. I didn't checked the Cocoapod first, but it's 1.0.1 @BHendricks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your essentially getting a mismatch between your cocoapods version of Realm and the version RealmBrowser is expecting. I think you have 2 options:

1) Upgrade RealmSwift cocoapods to match what RealmBrowser is expecting
2) Downgrade RealmBrowser version to match what version of RealmSwift cocoapods you have

The issue you're seeing of `fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: ... "Unable to open a realm at path ... Unsupported Realm file format version."` is because the `RealmBrowser` application is upgrading your realm database file, and then when you go back to the application, it is now in a "too-upgraded" format, so to speak.

Comment: Thank you, I understand totally what you mean. So I think I tried already the  first option. I mean I have installed the latest realm browser version and installed the latest realmswift cocoapods version. I expect that these to versions should work together, but in my case not. So maybe there is something else wrong. I will try now your second option, to downgrade the realmbrowser and try to get a match

Comment: Installed v1.0.2 [realm browser](https://github.com/realm/realm-browser-osx/releases/tag/1.0.2) and first used it with `pod 'RealmSwift', '~> 0.98'`, it worked. Then I tried to work with the latest realm swift version and opened the file with the older realm browser version. The message `'default' could not be opened. It may be encrypted, ...` appeared, which made sense. So I opened the file with the latest realm browser again and then there was no message with `proceed with upgrade`. Like expected. I don't know what really brought the solution.Anyway thanks pointing me in the right direction